# What does the number of title bar reflect on SuperUser?

Tags: support

I am seeing this number in the title bar of my browser when I log into Super User. This is second day running that it shows up in the title bar. What does it represent? Neither is it the number of unread messages (because there are none!), nor the number of questions I have asked, and definitely not my reputation. When I started typing this question, the number being displayed was (6). By the time finished typing this question, it had risen to (12). And by the time I ended finally posting this question (after attaching the screenshot), it had risen to (19)!!!

[image: Notice not only the number, but also that I don't have any unread messages.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the number of question with new activity.

Look at the grey bar in your picture:
[image]

Comment: Palm face plant...

Comment: -1 arrow doesn't match.